How do I add data from one column of a table to a new table?
So I have a table called
layoffs 

with 9 columns.
I want to create a table called
layoffs_copy 

which has 10 columns. 9 of them have the same data as the
layoffs

table. I want to paste data from a table called
new_dates 

to the 10th column of
layoffs_copy

in the same order. How do I do this?
Tried so far:
INSERT INTO layoffs_copy
SELECT *
FROM layoffs
and wanted to add the last column data next but get the "SQL error or missing database (table layoffs_copy has 10 columns but 9 values were supplied" error

First a table is not considered to be in any order, so there is no concept of "in the same order" unless the order is specified (or otherwise implied as is the case in the demo below).
Otherwise it is simply a matter of extracting the additional column and perhaps specifying the columns explicitly.
So something along the lines of
INSERT INTO layoffs_copy SELECT *, (SELECT the_data FROM new_dates WHERE expression_to_suit) FROM layoffs;


noting that the_data and expression_to_suit are descriptive rather than specific values.

Consider the following demo:-
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS layoffs;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS layoffs_copy;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS new_dates;
/* Create the 3 tables */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_dates (old_date,new_date);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS layoffs (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS layoffs_copy (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10);
/* Load some data into the new_dates table */
INSERT INTO new_dates VALUES ('a','A'),('b','B'),('c','C'),('d','D'),('e','E');
INSERT INTO layoffs VALUES 
    ('a','aa','aaa','aaaa','aaaaa','aaaaaa','aaaaaaa','aaaaaaaa','aaaaaaaaa'),
    ('b','bb','bbb','bbbb','bbbbb','bbbbbb','bbbbbbb','bbbbbbbb','bbbbbbbbb'),
    ('c','cc','ccc','cccc','ccccc','cccccc','ccccccc','cccccccc','ccccccccc'),
    ('a','xx','xxx','xxxx','xxxxx','xxxxxx','xxxxxxx','xxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxx'),
    ('z','zz','zzz','zzzz','zzzzz','zzzzzz','zzzzzzz','zzzzzzzz','zzzzzzzzz')
;
INSERT INTO layoffs_copy SELECT 
    *,
    /* The additional data aka the 10th column */
    (SELECT new_date FROM new_dates WHERE new_dates.old_date = layoffs.c1) 
FROM layoffs;

/* Get the resultant data */
SELECT * FROM layoffs_copy;

/* Cleanup Demo Environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS layoffs;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS layoffs_copy;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS new_dates;

This results in:-


So the respective (order) data has been added from the new_dates table as column c10 EXCEPT where there is no such respective value for when the c1 column is z so c10 is null (the coalesce function could correct this).

the respective value/order is according to the column c1 matching the column old_date, of course this is a relatively simple example


Hence the first row output is the first row from the layoffs table plus the respective new_date value from the new_dates table and so on.

of note is the row where most of the data is formed from x's (4th row), as the c1 column has a value of a so value A is obtained from the new_dates table.



The demo assumes that columns are like for like with the additional 10th additional column added.
In regard to explicit column names then consider, for example, a table called other_copy defined using:-
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS other_copy (c10,c8,c6,c4,c2,c1,c3,c5,c7,c9);

Then using:-
INSERT INTO other_copy SELECT 
    *,
    /* The additional data aka the 10th column */
    (SELECT new_date FROM new_dates WHERE new_dates.old_date = layoffs.c1) 
FROM layoffs;

would result in:-

i.e. the columns have been processed according to their order not their name
so data from C1 has been placed into column c10 and so on.
However if explicit column names are used as per:-
INSERT INTO other_copy (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10) SELECT 
    c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,
    /* The additional data aka the 10th column */
    (SELECT new_date FROM new_dates WHERE new_dates.old_date = layoffs.c1) AS c10
FROM layoffs;

The result is:-

i.e. the value extracted from column c1 has been placed into column c1 and so on.
